# Strip leading and trailing whitespace when piping to GNU parallel

Tags: pipe, gnu-parallel, whitespace

When I try to write a pipeline like this:

```
git branch | rg '^\*' | parallel git pull {}
```

I run into a problem with whitespace. Because the branch names have leading whitespace, parallel ends up attempting to run `git pull '  foo'` which is wrong.

Is there an argument for GNU Parallel that says "strip trailing/leading whitespace"? Alternatively, is there a separate program that does this?

I am aware that I could:

- Use `cut -c 3-` but this only works if leading space is consistent
- Use `sed` or `awk`, but these result in having to type a complex expression every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--trim rl`

```
git branch | rg -v '^\*' | parallel --dr --trim rl git pull {}
```